# Using jquery's after with a divs attribute

Tags: jquery

How can I use [jQuery’s `after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert data after a div with a certain attribute?

My `<div>`s go like this

```
<div id="mod" mod-id="1" mod-user="user1">
Content 1
</div>

<div id="mod" mod-id="2" mod-user="user2">
Content 2
</div>

<div id="mod" mod-id="3" mod-user="user3">
Content 3
</div>
```

Here, how can I tell jQuery’s `after()` to insert data after `id="mod" and mod-id="2"`?

I can tell `after()` to insert after `id="mod"`, but don't know how to tell it to do it based on a `div`'s data attribute.

Comment: Why not just use data-attrname and follow html5 standards, this will allow you to get the values using jquery's built in .data(). http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs must be unique, you can use classes instead and instead of using custom attributes, you can use HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<div class="mod" data-mod-id="1" data-mod-user="user1">
  Content 1
</div>

<div class="mod" data-mod-id="2" data-mod-user="user2">
  Content 2
</div>

<div class="mod" data-mod-id="3" data-mod-user="user3">
  Content 3
</div>
```

Now you can select the element using class and attribute selectors.

```
$('div.mod[data-mod-id="2"]').after('data');
```

Comment: I like your example I was going to post an answer with a jsfiddle but its pretty similar to this asnwer: http://jsfiddle.net/dRJaH/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot have more then one same ID. Change them to classes. Now that it is a class,

```
var field = $('.mod');

field.each(function(){
     if($(this).attr('mod-id')==2){
           $(this).after();
     }
});
```

Or

```
$('.mod[mod-id=2]').after();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[id=mod]").each(function() {
   if ($(this).attr("mod-id") == 2) {
      $(this).after("CVVVVVVVVVV");
   }
});
```

Comment: this will make sure that the data which is added is after a div with id mod and mod-id 2

Comment: possible, but expensive because the each :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
$( '[id=mod][mod-id=2]' ).after( 'xy' );​
```

but you really shouldn't use ids more then once!
Its also uncommon to use custom attributes like `mod-id`, better use the data attributes since html 5, for example `data-mod-id`